# Work for a vector field

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Find the work done against $F(x,y) = (-2y,x)$ along $C = \left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid  y=x^2\right\}$ between $(0,0)$ and $(2,4)$.

I understand that I need to perform a line integral for this problem..

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to parametrize the curve. In other words, the first thing to do is to find an application $\alpha : I \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\alpha(I) = C$ and such that there's $t_1 \in I$ and $t_2 \in I$ such that $\alpha(t_1) = (0,0)$ and $\alpha(t_2) = (2,4)$.

The points is that you know that for each point on that curve, $y =x^2$, so the most reasonable application to present is $\alpha(t) = (t, t^2)$. It satisfies $\alpha(0) = (0,0)$ and it satisfies $\alpha(2) = (2,4)$ so that both points are in there. If you set $I=(0,2)$ you'll get only the piece of the curve you're interested in.

Well, now let's use the definition of line integral. The line integral of $F$ over $C$ is:

$$\int_C F=\int_I \left \langle(F\circ\alpha), \alpha'\right\rangle$$

Now substituting what we got this is the same as:

$$\int_C F = \int_0^2 \left \langle F(t, t^2), (1, 2t)\right \rangle dt$$

Now $F(t, t^2) = (-2t^2, t)$ and so this inner product allows us to write this as:

$$\int_C F = \int_0^2 -2t^2 + 2t^2 dt = 0$$

I hope you understood the reasoning: find a way to parametrize the path, compose the field with the parametrization so that you get an expression for the field along the path, take the dot product with the tangent to the path at each point. You'll have now a single variable function that you can integrate on the interval that interests to you.

Comment: I believe I do understand. Does the -2t^2 + 2t^2 come from <F(t,t^2),(1,2t)>? As in, the one get's multiplied by -2t^2 in F(t,t^2) and the 2t multiplies the t to get 2t^2?

Comment: Exactly. This bracket notation is just the standard notation for the dot produtc (or more generally the inner product).

Comment: Great! Thank you. What are the resulting units? Newtons? (N)

Comment: Well, it might be good to you to know that this is a little more general than just "finding work". This is a geometrical construction only, so that using units amounts to putting constants to rescale things. But if you really want it, you can use the standar units. In that case the components of $F$ will be in Newtons $(N)$, the components of $\alpha$ in meters $(m)$ and the resulting things as you can see from the construction will be in Joules $(J)$.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that a line integral is what you want.  You can parameterize $C$ as $(t,t^2)$ with $t$ ranging from $0$ to $2$.  At each point, the work is $\vec F \cdot \vec {ds}$, so evaluate the tangent vector in terms of $t$ and integrate.

Comment: Does t range from 0 to 2 to represent x? So this is F = xi-2yj . Correct?

Comment: @cppCharizard:   No, note the order.  $\vec F(x,y)=-2y\hat i +x \hat j$